# Replace "\" with "\/" in C#

Tags: c#, escaping

I'm trying to change a string that has "/" to "\/" for a regex match.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
var test = "test/txt";
var testResult = test.Replace("/", @"\/");
var testResult2 = test.Replace("/", "\\/");
var testResult3 = @test.Replace("/", "\\/");
var testResult4 = test.Replace("/",@"\").Replace(@"\","\\/");
var testResult5 = test.Replace("/", @"\/").Replace("\\\\", "\\");
```

They all return "test\\/txt", I want "test\/txt".

I've seen the answers to replace / with \, and that works fine , when I try to put the / back in the same thing happens (testResult4).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your title talks about replacing backslash, but all your sample code is replacing a forward slash. Which are you actually interested in? And are you certain that you're looking at the actual contents of the string, rather than just what the debugger shows? Note that the debugger will show you an escaped value...

Comment: My bad, the preview wasn't escaping everything correctly, I just edited it.

Comment: [`String.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) has nothing to do with regexes, it does a simple string find and replace. To use regexes you need to use [`Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: [Your example code returns all expected results: test\/txt](https://dotnetfiddle.net/J5h3Vm)

Comment: \ is used for escape sequences. therfor in order to have one \ you must type two, you get it ? :D

Comment: Again, I suspect you're just looking in the debugger, which will be escaping the string. Print the value out on the console instead.

Comment: Yeah I was looking at the debugger, thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works fine:

```
var testResult = test.Replace("/", @"\/");
```

But when you watch `testResult` in debug mode it shows `"test\\/txt"`.

Print `testResult` to console or debug and you will see result you expect:

```
Debug.WriteLine(testResult);
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(testResult);
```

In debug you get double `\` because it is escape symbol. So, in watch you get `test\\/txt` but it is result you expect - `test\/txt`.

Comment: Yep, was looking at debugger, duh. Thank you very much, I'll accept in a couple of minutes